# Moving data from Oracle to SQL Server : Table size optimization

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl

I am loading data using SSIS from Oracle to an SQL Server database. One table I moved had a size of 4 MB under Oracle but when loaded to SQL Server, the size grows to 7.96 MB!

I analyzed the size (in KB) depending on the rows inserted and got the following results:

```
Rows    SQL Server  Oracle
10      16          64
50      48          64
100     88          64
150     128         128
200     168         128
250     208         128
300     248         128
350     288         192
400     328         192
450     368         192
500     408         192
550     448         256
600     488         256
650     528         256
700     568         256
750     648         320
800     688         320
```

I am suspecting that the datatypes used in SQL Server should be readapted. Here is a summary of the structure of the tables used in Oracle and SQL Server:

```
Oracle_DataType     SQL_Server_Datatype     #OfColumns
DATE                datetime                2
INTEGER             int                     1
NUMBER(1,0)         numeric(1, 0)           3
NUMBER(15, 5)       numeric(15, 5)          52
NUMBER(2, 0)        numeric(2, 0)           1
NUMBER(3, 0)        numeric(3, 0)           5
NUMBER(3, 1)        numeric(3, 1)           1
NUMBER(5, 0)        numeric(5, 0)           1
NUMBER(5, 2)        numeric(5, 2)           4
NUMBER(6, 0)        numeric(6, 0)           1
NUMBER(8, 3)        numeric(8, 3)           2
NUMBER(8, 4)        numeric(8, 4)           1
NUMBER(9, 0)        numeric(9, 0)           7
NUMBER(9, 3)        numeric(9, 3)           6
VARCHAR2(1)         nvarchar(1)             1
VARCHAR2(12)        nvarchar(12)            1
VARCHAR2(13)        nvarchar(13)            1
VARCHAR2(14)        nvarchar(14)            1
VARCHAR2(16)        nvarchar(16)            3
VARCHAR2(20)        nvarchar(20)            1
VARCHAR2(24)        nvarchar(24)            1
VARCHAR2(80)        nvarchar(80)            1
```

Do you have any idea if it will be possible to reduce the size in SQL Server so it could, at least, matches the size in Oracle?

Thanks,

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If 2008+ use the `date` datatype there (though this will have only a minor impact on size)

Comment: I use SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition, it's true that the impact of date datatype will be negligeable since there is only 2 columns using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Piotr for your suggestion. I find what really causes such big divergence between Oracle and SQL Server! It's due to NUMBER / NUMERIC data type (notice that 85 columns use NUMBERC/NUMBER datatype) !

While the storage size of a NUMBER(p,s) data vary under Oracle depending on the value of stored number, the size of NUMERIC(p,s) number still constant on SQL Server, whatever the value is!

For Instance:

- Under Oracle NUMBER(5,2) column we store the following values : (123.45, 12.23 and 1) the storage space is 4 bytes, 3 bytes and 1 bytes respectively, what sum up to **8 bytes**
- However, under SQL Server NUMERIC(5,2) column the storage required for all the three values is 5 bytes what sum up to **15 bytes**... (almoste twice the space under Oracle)

For more details check these two resources:

- [decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) from Books Online
- [Size of NUMBER](http://fredericktang.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/size-of-number/)(for Oracle)

Comment: There is a `vardecimal` storage format in SQL Server enterprise edition BTW but that is deprecated in favour of more general page / row compression now (you say you are using Enterprise Edition so you can use this)

Comment: Here you can read more about 2008+ row compression: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/06/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-row-compression/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280576.aspx

Comment: I finaly resolved the issue by using the Row Compression feature. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try non unicode strings: `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`. Oracle's `VARCHAR2` isn't unicode datatype and in `nvarchar` every character takes 2 bytes instead of 1.